# KineticJS Inside of Shape and/or Fill not being rendered in Chrome under Windows 8

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, cross-platform, kineticjs

I created a simple multiplayer math game which uses KineticJS on the client side. I developed it in Linux and everything seemed to work fine and all the coding went smoothly. I noticed the other day, that when running it on OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) at work, my submission button and enter events on the input would not work. It did work on the iMac I tested it with that had 10.7 (Lion) installed. Today I booted my laptop into Windows 8 which I do not do often and tried to run my app.

Here is a link to my live web app: **[Get24](http://get24.jit.su)**

Here is a link to the Github project: [**CoryG89/Get24**](http://github.com/CoryG89/Get24)

I have also opened a [**Github issue about this**](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/311).

However, when I tried to run my app in Chrome on Windows 8, the layout of the page is all messed up. The buttons aren't colored and the target areas for the mouseover events are not lined up with the buttons. The game is not usable. There are no errors in the console. Using Firefox in Windows gives similar results to any browser running under Linux, it works perfectly.

Can anyone tell me why my app seems to be so operating system / browser dependent. Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else had this experience with KineticJS not working the same under different browsers and operating systems?

#### Update March 6, 2013

---

After further messing around with my simple game, I noticed that the `mouseover` and `click` events on my buttons were only working at the fill in Chrome Windows 8. I created this [**simple jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryG89/kZBzH/) which when viewed in Chrome on Windows 8 on my computer only renders the fill of the rectangle objects. The bottom rectangles show that when using `draggable` or the `click` event only the stroke of the rectangles will react to the mouse. Finally, I went looking around the web and this [**official tutorial the KineticJS Shape fill property**](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-fill-with-kineticjs/) has the same problem when viewed in Chrome on Windows 8. Firefox renders it just fine.

Does anyone have a workaround to get the fill property working in Chrome?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant, but the `type` on your script tags should probably be `text/javascript` because ECMAScript is DOM agnostic.

Comment: i havent had problems with kinetic between firefox and chrome

Comment: It's quite a widespread problem. The `fill` property isn't working at all on Chrome in Windows 8. I guess we'll have to wait for a fix to come out.

Comment: Looks like it, guess I am going to have to use something else besides Kinetic for now... I assumed it was going to be portable. Shame, I really like the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I feel pretty stupid because when I posted this question the newer version of KineticJS was already out. They do not list this bug being fixed in the change log, however, updating from v4.3.1 to v4.3.3 fixed this for me. My web app is now up and running just fine in Chrome Win8 for me. The tutorials that are linked to from the official KineticJS page are still running an older version and fill is broken in Chrome Win8. If anyone runs into this problem in the future, simply make sure you are on the latest version of Kinetic.

Answer (score 0):

As well there are a few changes in syntax between versions. Not really aware from witch version the shape syntax changed but updating from 4.0.5 to 4.4.0 you need to make the following changes to make it work

update to 4.4.0 and then...

```
 var circle = new Kinetic.Shape({
  //4.0.5 returns context instead of canvas
      drawFunc: function(canvas) {
        /*set var context geting that from canvas, As i said the new drawFunc returns canvas instead of context*/
        var context = canvas.getContext();


        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.arc(0, 0, (that.parameters.radius/2)-10, Math.PI*take_PI_from_o(angle.end.value), Math.PI*take_PI_from_o(angle.start.value), true);            
        context.closePath();

        //the following two commands are droped
        //this.fill(context); 
        //this.stroke(context);

        //and replaced with this one
        canvas.fillStroke(this);
      },
      fill: "#54CAFF",
      stroke: "#858585",
      strokeWidth: 4,
      rotationDeg:-90,
      x: angle.stage.getWidth() / 2,
      y: angle.stage.getHeight() / 2,

    });
```